# HTML5 video not loading properly in android's default browser

Tags: android, html, video

I am developing a web page that uses the HTML5 video tag. When I load the page in my ASUS eee pad transformer in the default browser I see a grey area with an icone in the middle instead of the video.

I then have to click in the video area for it to load and only then it is possible to play the video.

This only happens in the default browser. I have tried it on Chrome, Firefox and Opera and it always worked without me having to click the video area for it to load.

My question is. Why is this happening and is there anyway I can correct the issue?

I have tried using the atributes autobuffer and preload.

**UPDATE:**

I manage to make a workaround. I used Javascript on the page load and the video not only loads but also plays. So the problem where I would see a grey rectangle in which I would have to click to load the video is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing you can do I'm afraid, the default Android browser is incredibly fiddly with HTML5 video and you're lucky that you can play it at all!

Comment: That sucks. But I did manage to develop a workaround. Simply use Javascript and do video.play() and it will load automatically and play.

Comment: Yes I didn't mention that as you said it was working already?